# How to get the total number of hours based on users selected time in future

Tags: ios, swift

Is possible to find total number of hours when a user has selected a future time for example, if the current time is 12:00PM and user select to finish a task in the next 2 hours 2:00PM as the target time, how can I represent those 2 hours like this " Time to complete next task 2Hours"

Here is what I have so far:

```
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
    let date = formatter.dateFromString(time)!
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let component = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: date)
    print("Complete next task \(component.hour)HR")
```

This is what prints out:

```
Complete next task 20HR
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSDateComponentsFormatter`:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let startTime = calendar.dateWithEra(1, year: 2016, month: 6, day: 28, hour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
let endTime = calendar.dateWithEra(1, year: 2016, month: 6, day: 28, hour: 14, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!

let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.Hour, .Minute]
formatter.allowsFractionalUnits = true
formatter.unitsStyle = .Short
formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1

print("Complete next task:", formatter.stringFromDate(startTime, toDate: endTime)!)
```

It can handle multiple locales, take care of singular (`1 hr`) and plural (`2 hrs`) for you.

Comment: i am getting wrong answer with above solution, i selected 10:00PM it should print 1hr but instead it prints 0hr

Comment: What's your start time and end time?

Comment: `let startTime = calendar.dateWithEra(0, year: currentTime.year(), month: currentTime.month(), day: currentTime.day(), hour: currentTime.hour(), minute: currentTime.minute(), second: currentTime.second(), nanosecond: 0)
 let endTime = calendar.dateWithEra(0, year: selectedTime.year(), month: selectedTime.month(), day: selectedTime.day(), hour: selectedTime.hour(), minute: selectedTime.minute(), second: selectedTime.second(), nanosecond: 0)`

Comment: ```let currentTime = NSDate()```

Comment: In literal values please. What does `print(currentTime)` and `print(selectedTime)` give you?

Comment: `let selectedTime = formatter.dateFromString(time)!` is a time that users selects from DataPicker

Comment: currentTime -> 2016-06-29 01:21:47 +0000 
selectedTime ->  2016-06-29 03:21:41 +0000

Comment: Edited my answer to allow the `formatter` to use hour or minute, but only 1, not both